# Compare arrays and Return the Difference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array A in memory created at runtime and another array B saved in a mongo database. How can I efficiently get all the elements from A that are not in B?

You can assume that the array stored in mongodb is several orders of magnitude bigger than the array created at runtime, for that reason I think that obtaining the full array from mongo and computing the result would not be efficient, but I have not found any query operation in mongo that allows me to compute the result I want.

Note that the [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator does the opposite of what I want, i.e., it retrieves the elements from B that are not in A.

Example:

Array A, created in my appliction at runtime, is `[2, 3, 4]`.

Array B, stored in mongodb, is `[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10]`.

The result I expect is `[2, 4]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only things that "modify" the document in response are [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [`.mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/), where the former is the better option.

In that case you are asking for [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) which compares the "sets" and returns the "difference" between the two.

So representing a document with your array:

```
db.collection.insert({ "b": [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10] })
```

Run the aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ "$project": { "c": { "$setDifference": [ [2,3,4], "$b" ] } } }])
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596005eace45be96e2cb221b"), "c" : [ 2, 4 ] }
```

If you do not want "sets" and instead want to supply an array like `[2,3,4,4]` then you can compare with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) instead, if you have MongoDB 3.4 at least:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "c": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": [2,3,4,4],
        "as": "a",
        "cond": {
          "$not": { "$in": [ "$$a", "$b" ]  }
        }
      }
    }   
  }}
])
```

Or with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) in earlier versions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "c": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": [2,3,4,4],
        "as": "a",
        "cond": {
          "$not": {
            "$anyElementTrue": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$b",
                "as": "b",
                "in": {
                  "$eq": [ "$$a", "$$b" ]    
                }
              }    
            }
          }
        }    
      }
    }    
  }}
])
```

Where both would return:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("596005eace45be96e2cb221b"), "c" : [ 2, 4, 4 ] }
```

Which is of course "not a set" since the `4` was provided as input "twice" and is therefore returned "twice" as well.