# How to get all array items that don't exists in a specific attribute in all documents of a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Nodejs and MongoDB. In one of my tasks, I have a dynamic array of phone numbers like this:

```js
var INPUT_ARRAY = [ "1000000000", "1000000050", "1000000100", "1000000101" ];
```

this array will contains 2k-3k values. I also have a collection `employees` with employee details around 100000 documents like given below:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60536cc1aafebb0d10399df8"
  },
  "phone": "1000000000",
  "first_name": "john",
  "last_name": "doe"
}
```

I need to match dynamic array values against employee collections and need to return all the phone numbers from dynamic array that don't exists in employees collection.

I searched a lot for this and also checked following questions
[Compare arrays and Return the Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973140/compare-arrays-and-return-the-difference)
[MongoDB Find values passed in that don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394333/mongodb-find-values-passed-in-that-dont-match)

but these question's answer didn't worked for me.

Can somebody please help me to find a performance wise better solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION #1**:

```js
var INPUT_ARRAY = ["1000000000", "1000000050", "1000000100", "1000000101"]

db.employees.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            phone_numbers: { $push: "$phone" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            missingNumbers: {
                $filter: {
                    input: INPUT_ARRAY,
                    as: "phone_number",
                    cond: {
                        $not: {
                            $in: ["$$phone_number", "$phone_numbers"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**SOLUTION #2**: As suggested by @Joe in the comments:

```js
var INPUT_ARRAY = ["1000000000", "1000000050", "1000000100", "1000000101"]

db.employees.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            phone_numbers: { $push: "$phone" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            missingNumbers: {
                $setDifference: [INPUT_ARRAY, "$phone_numbers"]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "phone_numbers" : [
        "1000000000",
        "1000000050",
        "10000060"
    ],
    "missingNumbers" : [
        "1000000100",
        "1000000101"
    ]
}
```

`employees` collection

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:37:45 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60536cc1aafebb0d10399df8"),
    "phone" : "1000000000",
    "first_name" : "john",
    "last_name" : "doe"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:37:45 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60536cc1aafebb0d10399df9"),
    "phone" : "1000000050",
    "first_name" : "jane",
    "last_name" : "doe"
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/18/2021, 8:37:45 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60536cc1aafebb0d10399dfa"),
    "phone" : "10000060",
    "first_name" : "joe",
    "last_name" : "doe"
}
```

Comment: Could `$setDifference` be used instead of the filter?